# How to find wether a specific DOM is exist or not inside a DIV by javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div id='list'>
  <table id='1'></table>
  <table id='2'></table>
  <table id='r'></table>
  //And more...
</div>
```

All the tables are added dynamic by other codes. Also their ID are generated dynamic.

I hope to know that, when I need to add a new table, how can I check the new table's ID is already existed in the list or not? That is , how to check if a id is in the div or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery find() API to find an element within another.  [Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/find/).  The find() API lets you select as $() does, but within a target as the OP wants.  Note that find() also goes through all children of all levels, not just the direct children (grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc.).

Working [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mBbJx/) showing this API which finds the target span by ID in one DIV but not in another.

Answer (score 1):

`$(#id).length > 0` means id already exists.

Comment: Thank you! Than if I hope to check specially if the id exist in a particular DIV? Like under 'list' in this case?

Comment: $(#id).length > 0 && $(#id).closest('#list').length > 0

Comment: Or `$("#list #"+id).length > 0`.

Comment: @Amareswar Thank you! I have tried your method. It works on some of the elements but not all...Let me explain detail. I have ID's in the form like:#32bacee1-8f47-468c-b5de-c3be1f94d8da. And I do have the same ID existed in another list. The tricky part is, when I use your method to check if the element is already in the list, some will work, will some will not. Like this id 32bacee1-8f47-468c-b5de-c3be1f94d8da will always come to a 0 which could be added many times, and other id 32bacee1-8f47-468c-b5de-c3be1f94d8da could be detected just fine.